# How to proper align after CSS column-count

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm working on an unordered list. I'm trying to display the content in multiple columns. I've managed to do this with CSS's column-count, however the content is not displayed properly. It seems like the first item of the list is placed on the second position, resulting in a crooked list.

Instead of this output:

```
A  F  K
B  G  L
C  H  M
D  I  N
E  J  O
```

I get:

```
   E  J  O    
A  F  K  
B  G  L 
C  H  M
D  I  N
```

or, when I have two items to place in two columns, I want:

```
A  B
```

but I get:

```
   A  B
```

So it seems like the first position is always skipped. I've looked for ways t solve this but couldn't find others with this problem, mostly people have other alignment issues. This is the CSS of the div that contains the ul:

```
div.partlist { 
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Anyone any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show me your html?

Comment: There is probably an element before the **A** in your (possibly broken) HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are missing a reset on the `ul/li` to remove the default margin/padding.

```css
div.partlist {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="partlist">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```